# STLport error: '__cxa_demangle' is not a member of 'abi' for boost library

Tags: c++, boost, android-ndk, boost-log, android-stlport

I have been trying to compile a piece of code which needs boost logging , things are fine when I try to compile with gnustl but when I switch to stlport the compiler, cribs loud with the following message.

```
In file included from   /boost/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_value.hpp:23:0,
                 from /boost/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_value_set.hpp:27,
                 from  /boost/include/boost/log/core/record.hpp:21,
                 from  /boost/include/boost/log/core/core.hpp:23,
                 from  /boost/include/boost/log/core.hpp:20,
                 from  /boost/include/boost/log/common.hpp:22,
                 from /MyApp/FrameWorkLog.cpp:30:
 /boost/include/boost/log/utility/type_info_wrapper.hpp: In member function 'std::string boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::type_info_wrapper::pretty_name() const':
 /boost/include/boost/log/utility/type_info_wrapper.hpp:131:33: error: '__cxa_demangle' is not a member of 'abi'
```

I don't want to use gnustl for many reason.

More information: 
The following is my Application.mk file configs

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.6
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
APP_STL := stlport_static  # For Static build
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
```

Boost library version : 1.54.0

I tried building my app both 9c and 10b android ndk, but no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /boost/include/boost/log/utility/type_info_wrapper.hpp:131:33: error: '__cxa_demangle' is not a member of 'abi'

Looking at the NDK's `doc/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html`, there's no mention of it. It looks like your have four choices.

First, you might be able to use [Boost 1.56](http://www.boost.org/users/download/) because it appears [`type_info_wrapper.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/log/utility/type_info_wrapper.hpp) does not use `__cxa_demangle`. I could be wrong, but I did not find it in the 1.56 header.

Second, configure Boost 1.54 such that `BOOST_LOG_HAS_CXXABI_H` is *not* defined. That will guard the use of `abi::__cxa_demangle` in 1.54's [`type_info_wrapper.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/log/utility/type_info_wrapper.hpp).

I don't know how to do it because I rarely use Boost, but I would probably hack it through `config.hpp` as follows. The Boost folks might know a `bjam` configuration option, so hopefully one of them will provide feedback.

```
// cxxabi.h availability macro
#if defined(BOOST_CLANG)
#   if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<cxxabi.h>)
#       define BOOST_LOG_HAS_CXXABI_H
#   endif
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__QNX__)
#   define BOOST_LOG_HAS_CXXABI_H
#endif

// Add these lines as a hack
#ifdef (__ANDROID__)
# undef BOOST_LOG_HAS_CXXABI_H
#endif
```

Third, try linking with one of the libraries that provide it. Unfortunately, it does not look like STLport provides it. It appears GAbi++ and GNU STL provide it:

```
$ cd /opt/android-ndk-r9/
$ find . -iname cxxabi.h
./sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/include/cxxabi.h
./sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include/cxxabi.h
./sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/cxxabi.h
./sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include/cxxabi.h
./sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/cxxabi.h
```

Fourth, port `__cxa_demangle` from one of the STL libraries that provide it. You can find the source code for the NDK libraries at [Android Tools Project](http://tools.android.com/overview/ndk-git).

Comment: I did not try boost 1.56, hopefully in near future I would try that. I can't use gnustl because my all other libraries are compiled with stlport so eventually it would lead to problems at linking.

I did use the -E flag to see what are the libraries are included and it turns out it is including /android-ndk-r10b/sources/cxx-stl//gabi++/include/cxxabi.h, but yes I just want to confirm that gabi++ don't even have __cxa_demangle , but gnu-libstdc++/4.8 and 4.6 has it. But that would perhaps get included only when I choose gnustl.

Comment: @Abhiram Mishra - Yeah, I'm with you. I use STLport too. But I don't recall having the problem (yet)... I use STLport for licensing reasons. GPL is toxic for non-free projects.

Comment: Also want to add; if I choose NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8 I get even more errors , and in the -E flag and the intermediate file looks like android-ndk-r10b/sources/cxx-stl//gabi++/include/cxxabi.h

Comment: +1 for multiple options provided. I will come back and update which one suited me the best.